# jquery draggable and sortable no plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I hate plugins so I found a way to drag and sort html elements using only jquery....

The way it works is that I have four divs absolutely positioned inside a relatively positioned div. When you mousedown one of the four divs the code gets the postion of the div and saves it on two global variables. The code binds the document to the mousemove event and gets the position of the mouse cursor. When you move the mouse around the position of the mouse cursor is assigned to the div with the css() method (left mouse cursor coordinate minus half the width of the div and top mouse cursor corrdinate minus half the height of the div). If the right edge or the left edge of the div moves out of bounds of the container div the the div is reverted to its old position with the css() method. When you mouseup the div the code gets the new coordinates of the div and loops through the other divs for their coordinates and determines which div is closest by position (which div's top coordinate is at most 50px away from the current div's current top coordinate and left coordinate is also at most 50px away from the current div's  current left coordinate). The code then unbinds the mousemove from the document and swaps the position of the closest div with the oldest position of the div that just got the mouseup.

My html code:

```
    <div style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid red;">



<div class="draggable"  id="div1" style=" position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 150px; margin: 1px 2px; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: 1px solid red;"  >

<table border="1" width="250" height="140" align="center" style=""><tbody>
<tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

1

</td></tr>
<tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   


</td></tr></tbody></table>

</div>

<div class="draggable"  id="div2" style=" position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 150px; margin: 1px 2px; top: 0px; left: 400px; border: 1px solid red;"  >

<table border="1" width="250" height="140" align="center" style=""><tbody>
<tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

2

</td></tr>
<tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   


</td></tr></tbody></table>

</div>


<div class="draggable" id="div3" style=" position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 150px; margin: 1px 2px; top: 200px; left: 0px; border: 1px solid red;"  >

<table border="1" width="250" height="140" align="center" style=""><tbody>
<tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

3

</td></tr>
<tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   


</td></tr></tbody></table>

</div>


<div class="draggable"  id="div4" style=" position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 150px; margin: 1px 2px; top: 200px; left: 400px; border: 1px solid red;"  >

<table border="1" width="250" height="140" align="center" style=""><tbody>
<tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

4

</td></tr>
<tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   


</td></tr></tbody></table>



</div>




</div>
```

My jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


$(".draggable").mousedown(function(){

dragging = $(this).prop("id");
oldTop = $(this).position().top; 
oldLeft = $(this).position().left;

$("#"+dragging).css("cursor", "move");

$(document).mousemove(function(event){

var top = event.pageY - ($("#"+dragging).height()/2); 
var left = event.pageX - ($("#"+dragging).width()/2); 
var bottom = event.pageY + ($("#"+dragging).height()/2); 
var right = event.pageX + ($("#"+dragging).width()/2);

if(top > 0 && left > 0 && bottom < 500 && right < 800){ 

 $("#"+dragging).css( "left", left+"px").css("top", top+"px");

}else{

$("#"+dragging).css("cursor", "normal").css( "left", oldLeft+"px").css("top", oldTop+"px");

$(document).unbind("mousemove");

}

});




}).mouseup(function(){

newLeft = $(this).position().left;  
newTop = $(this).position().top;
var i = 0;

$(document).unbind("mousemove");

$(".draggable").not($(this)).each(function(){

var posLeft = $(this).position().left; 
var posTop = $(this).position().top;

var topDiff = Math.abs(posTop - newTop); 
var leftDiff = Math.abs(posLeft - newLeft); 



if(leftDiff <= 50 && topDiff <= 50){ 

$("#"+dragging).css("cursor", "normal").css( "left", posLeft+"px").css("top", posTop+"px");

$(this).css("left", oldLeft+"px").css("top", oldTop+"px");

i++;

}

}); 


if(i == 0){  

$("#"+dragging).css("cursor", "normal").css( "left", oldLeft+"px").css("top", oldTop+"px"); 

}

});



});
```

The code works fine. Only thing that it does unexpectedly is that div1 can't be dragged for sorting with any other div, div2 can only be dragged for sorting with div1, div3 can be dragged for sorting with div1 and div2 only, and div4 can be dragged for sorting with any of the divs. The code should work so that any div can be dragged for sorting with the rest of the divs.

Instead, if you drag div1 and position it right above div2 or div3 or div4 (position div1 so that its top coordinate is at most 50px away from div2 top coordinate and div1 left coordinate is at most 50px away from div2 left coordinate) it will just revert to its old position, even though my code doesn't specify that should happen. The two divs should instead swap positions. Same thing happens when dragging div2 to div3 or div4 and when dragging div3 to div4.  I don't know why this happens. I think it has to do with the foreach I have near the end of the jquery code. I don't really know. If anyone knows how to improve on this code I'd greatly appreciate it.

What I hope to be able to further do with the code is:

- drag any div for sorting with any of the rest of the divs.
- if it is ever possible to use relatively positioned div1, div2, div3, and div4 and still be able to drag any div for sorting with any other div.

Also I am not so good with javascript. So the less javascript the better.

Thank You.

Comment: Please, indent your code in an organized fashion. It does wonders for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have mentioned that you hate plugins. Also you have mentioned that you use jQuery.

Just out of curiosity why not to use jQueryUI ? It has [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) features. On StackOverflow you would have 100s of questions already answered for you.

IMO, what you are trying to do is re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I don't really understand the plugin. I understand my code and I want to improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the code that does exactly what I was looking for. Most importantly, it does not require absolute positioning. It uses static positioning of elements, which is perfect.

Everything works fine but something unexpected that happens is that initially, the cursor is centered vertically on the div but not horizontally or along the width of the div when dragging it, although it should have been. Fixed that by doing something unexpected. See comment on jquery code.

html changed:

```
<table id="container" border="0" width="800" height="500" align="center" style="position: relative; border: 1px solid red;"><tbody>
<tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">


    <div class="draggable"  id="div1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 1px 2px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;"  >

        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" style=""><tbody>
        <tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

        1

        </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   


        </td></tr></tbody></table>

    </div>

    <div class="draggable"  id="div2" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 1px 2px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;"  >

        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" style=""><tbody>
        <tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

        2

        </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   

        </td></tr></tbody></table>

    </div>


    <div class="draggable" id="div3" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 1px 2px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block"  >

        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" style=""><tbody>
        <tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

        3

        </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   

        </td></tr></tbody></table>

    </div>


    <div class="draggable"  id="div4" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 1px 2px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;"  >

        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" style=""><tbody>
        <tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

        4

        </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   

        </td></tr></tbody></table>

    </div>


    <div class="draggable"  id="div5" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 1px 2px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;"  >

        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" style=""><tbody>
        <tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

        5

        </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   

        </td></tr></tbody></table>

    </div>

    <div class="draggable"  id="div6" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 1px 2px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;"  >

        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" style=""><tbody>
        <tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

        6

        </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   

        </td></tr></tbody></table>

    </div>

    <div class="draggable"  id="div7" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; margin: 1px 2px; border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block;"  >

        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" align="center" style=""><tbody>
        <tr><td width="" height="" align="center" valign="center">

        7

        </td></tr>
        <tr><td width="" height="20" align="center" valign="top" colspan="" style="">   

        </td></tr></tbody></table>

    </div>



</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


    $(document).on("mousedown", ".draggable", function(){

        sortable = $(this);
        sortableDomPos = sortable.index();
        sortable.fadeTo(1, 0);
        oldLeft = sortable.position().left; oldTop = sortable.position().top;

        dragging = $(this).clone();
        dragging.css("position", "absolute").css("left", oldLeft+"px").css("top", oldTop+"px").css("pointer-events", "none").appendTo("#container");


        $(document).mousemove(function(event){

            var top = event.pageY - ($(dragging).height()/2); 
            var left = event.pageX - ($(dragging).width()); // ** should be ** var left = event.pageX - ($(dragging).width()/2);
            var bottom = event.pageY + ($(dragging).height()/2); 
            var right = event.pageX + ($(dragging).width()/2);

            if(top > 0 && left > 0 && bottom < 500 && right < 900){ 
                $(dragging).css( "left", left+"px").css("top", top+"px");
            }else{
                $(document).unbind("mousemove"); $(dragging).remove(); sortable.fadeTo(1, 1);
            }

        });



    });


    $(document).on("mouseup", ".draggable, #container", function(){

        $(document).unbind("mousemove"); $(dragging).remove();  sortable.fadeTo(1, 1);

        if($(this).prop("class") == "draggable"){

            var thisDomPos = $(this).index();

            if(sortableDomPos >= thisDomPos){
                sortable.insertAfter($(this)); $(this).insertAfter($(".draggable").eq(sortableDomPos));
            }
            else{
                sortable.insertBefore($(this)); $(this).insertBefore($(".draggable").eq(sortableDomPos));
            }

        }

    });


});
```